# classic asp server.transfer error

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a file failed.asp in folder abc. Now i want to redirect my user.asp page in folder xyz to page failed.asp when there is a error. When i have my failed.asp in same folder as my user.asp it does not give me error but if i use virtual path in server.transfer it is giving me error. How can i fix this.

Server.Transfer("failed.asp") --Works
Server.Transfer("abc/failed.asp") or Server.Transfer("../abc/failed.asp") --fails saying error when loading file

does not work what is the possible work around for this issue.

Comment: You can call the Redirect method of your request object, but I'm not sure it works in classic asp.

Comment: Need to use server.transfer only.

Comment: Maybe parent path is disabled in your IIS. Follow [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332117) to learn more and possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

Server.Transfer("/abc/failed.asp") should work. Note that the root path starts with a forward slash.